# On-submit directive not working AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to write my first simple webapp using Angular. I'm getting problem when I'm trying to submit form. App is not reacting and there aren't any errors in browser console. Here is my controller :

```
 angular.module('myApp.add_new_worker',         

 ['ngRoute','myApp.services','ngResource'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/newworker', {
        templateUrl: 'newworker/form.html',
        controller: 'addNewWorkerController'
    });
}])

.controller('addNewWorkerController', ['$scope','formService',function($scope,formService) {
    $scope.formInfo = [];
    this.saveData=function () {
        window.alert("HEllo world").

        formService.save($scope.formInfo);
}}] );
```

My service code:

```
 var service=angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);
    service.factory('formService',['$resource',function($resource){

return $resource('http://localhost:8080/worker/add',{},{
  save:{
    method:'POST'
  }  
}
)
 }]);
```

And I'm trying to use saveData() function in this way

```
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-           controller="addNewWorkerController" ngSubmit="saveData()">
     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
           <input type="submit"   class="btn btn-success"/>
         </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Does your actual code have the giant space between `ng-            controller`?

Comment: Is it actually "ngSubmit" in your HTML or "ng-submit"?

Comment: no,  this is just problem with formatting code on stackoverflow, @JonK ngSubmit

Comment: So you know where is your (first) problem: Look -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit, the correct is `ng-submit`.

Comment: still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Put saveData on the $scope.

```
$scope.saveData = function () {
    window.alert("HEllo world").
    formService.save($scope.formInfo);
};
```

Comment: in this way           $scope.saveData=this.saveData(); ?

Comment: @KrystianDrach no you do not need to add saveData to "this", only the $scope.  Also make sure to use the proper ng-submit syntax instead of ngSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax of ng-submit is incorrect, you should use 'ng-submit=saveData()'.

I strongly recommend initializing scope objects that you use for your forms using ng-model directive, so in your submit method you send the object as a parameter and send it to your service in the method definition inside the controller. So your code would be like so:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-controller="addNewWorkerController" ng-submit="saveData(formInfo)">
  <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" ng-model="formInfo.name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" ng-model="formInfo.password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <input type="submit"   class="btn btn-success"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And your saveData() method should be in the scope, like: '$scope.saveData() = function....' instead of 'this.saveData()' , so it can be accessed from your view.

And then, there is no need to initialize $scope.formInfo in your controller.

Comment: ok but now i have this kind of error in console : TypeError: Cannot read property 'formService' of undefined

Comment: @KrystianDrach you should call formService directly, not as a property of a object. Can you post the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

**Notes:**

1. `ng-controller` attribute is malformed;
2. ngSubmit isn't a valid directive, it's [ng-submit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit);
3. The function `saveData()` should be inserted into `$scope`, otherwise it can't be called in view.

Here's a snippet working, with all mistakes solved:

```js
angular.module('myApp.add_new_worker', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.services', 'ngResource'])

// .config(function($routeProvider) {
//   $routeProvider.when('/newworker', {
//     templateUrl: 'newworker/form.html',
//     controller: 'addNewWorkerController'
//   });
// })

.controller('addNewWorkerController', function($scope, formService) {
  $scope.formInfo = [];
  $scope.saveData = function() {
    console.log('Post!!!');

    formService.save($scope.formInfo);
  }
});

angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('formService', function($resource) {

  return $resource('https://google.com', {}, {
    save: {
      method: 'POST'
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp.add_new_worker">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.5.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="addNewWorkerController">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-controller="addNewWorkerController" ng-submit="saveData(formInfo)">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="formInfo.name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" ng-model="formInfo.password">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```